# Ethereum Genesis file private network

Tags: ethereum

Need some basic info on ethereum.
Can I send 1 million transaction in a day in ethereum private network?If yes, how much gas will be required(approx)?

How much of maximum gas limit can we define for a node?

And I have a doubt that if I reinitialize the genesis file then, whether a new blockchain is started or it continues with the older one?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I send 1 million transaction in a day in ethereum private network?

Yes, that's around 12 transactions per second, [that's no problem](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1037/87).

```
1000000 / (24 * 60 * 60) = 11.574
```

> If yes, how much gas will be required(approx)?

A transaction without anything else but value transfer costs 21,000 gas.

That is 21 billion gas per 1 million transactions per day, or (assuming a 15 seconds block time) 3.6 million gas per block:

```
 21000000000 / (24 * 60 * 4) = 3645833.333
```

The default gas limit on Ethereum public network is 4712388 (1.5 * pi million). But it's trivial to increase the target gas limit.

> How much of maximum gas limit can we define for a node?

In theory, you should be able to set the gas limit as high as you wish, however, that's not practicable, as discussed in [EIP-106](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/106) which suggest limiting the maximum block gas limit to `2^63 - 1`.

> And I have a doubt that if I reinitialize the genesis file then, whether a new blockchain is started or it continues with the older one?

Yes, if you change the genesis, this will in most cases start a new blockchain.